# Illustrator pattern grid clipping image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, grids

[image]

How do I fix this? Pieces of the design are getting cut off (right and bottom side of the yellow, top and left side of the green).

Any help would be appreciated!

(to answer a reply that was deleted - there is no background, it is a clean vector, fully transparent)

Answer (score 0):

Guessing based upon video from comments: https://i.imgur.com/T55Fihx.mp4

If the green/yellow shapes are comprised of a bunch of little, *individual*, pieces ....

The negative offset in the pattern editor may be failing to replicate these **individual** pieces because they fall outside the pattern tile clipping area.

To correct this....

- Select all the green and choose `Object > Compound Path > Make`.
- Then do the same for the yellow.

*Now* create your pattern the same way you have.

By creating *compound shapes* of all the pieces, Illustrator sees the pieces as *one*, singular, object rather than a bunch of pieces. This means the shape *won't* be "clipped" as long as a part of it is within the pattern's tile.

Comment: Video that should hopefully answer your questions. I am fairly new to illustrator - thank you for your help! https://imgur.com/a/xefWT3U

Comment: @yen that is interesting because I can't replicate the issue: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8EzN.png) Guessing.. is the Green shape a group or compound path? and the Yellow shape? My only real guess would be if the shapes are all separate little pieces, the clipping may *not* be showing parts because they are clipped by the negative offset. But if the shapes are one object, they shouldn't be clipped like that.

Comment: So select all the green parts.. `Object  > Compound Path > Make` then repeat for all the yellow parts and then try creating the pattern again (the same way you do in the video).

Comment: YES! That was it, thank you SO SO much, Scott!

Comment: Glad that was it @yen I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: If you don't mind, may I ask a follow up question? Is there an easy way to export the swatch created? When I try to save it, it includes objects outside the boundaries of the tile. ~Thanks! <3

Comment: @yen export in what sense? AI patterns are for AI use only. They aren't inter-application transferable the way standard swatches are.